# Calculated fields and OData / WCF Data Service

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

I am trying to add some calculated fields to my Entity Framework model that is exposed externally using a WCF Data Service, the problem I have is that anything I try doesn't get exposed outside of my service.

I have tried adding the following code (Note: the actual method has business logic in the get/set methods):

```
public partial class myClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

However the field is still not returned in by OData, it seems OData only looks at the .edmx.

Currently the only option I can think of to solve this is to implement a `CLR function` and have my Entity Framework model look at a SQL `view` which calls my function for every returned row and calculates the value at the server side, and use stored procedure to update the entity. But I would rather not have to go through all this for what is effectively a simple (in .NET, but not-so in SQL) calculated field.

What other options are open to me for calculating this field?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that WCF DS only looks at the csdl if the provider is EF.

So you have couple of options

- Keep using EF provider and somehow add the columns to the CSDL. What I've seen people doing is add columns into the DB, but leave them empty and compute them in the EF classes (for example). But I'm sure there's other ways to do this as well.
- Use custom provider in which case you get full control over everything, but the amount of work to make this happen over EF based projection is huge. So unless you run into other problems I would not go that route.

Comment: For the first way, how/where can I compute those fields if my WcfDataService / Entity Context abstract this all away from me? There doesn't seem to be any location where I can set the values or call a method within my `WcfDataService` or a `partial class` of my type.

Comment: EF generates classes which are then exposed through WCF DS. Those classes live in your project. You can modify them to make the properties generated.